Python mailgun Api batch sender errorFix?
Hello people I am noob a python programing and bulk mail sending need help PLEASE.I am trying to send bulk mail with a code provided by them in a tutorial link below:
https://www.mailgun.com/blog/it-and-engineering/send-email-using-python/
I have a domain with verified dns bought from nanescheap I setup correctly the CNAME and the dns  also the mxa and mxb records.
I had put the generated api domain key and the api domain url but getting
ERROR:root:Could not send emails, reason: Forbidden
I will atach a screenshot of the program deleted only the api url and the key.Also I am from European Union my domain I registered as a Us one PLEASE help i will be extremely grateful.Screenshot with the error
Fix my code please.
ERROR:root:Could not send emails, reason: Forbidden

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
